# How can I get the random seed that was used from results and python random.getstate()?

Tags: python, random, random-seed, proof-of-work

So I run the following code to produce the following snippet around **8:30 est 3/10/2022.** I say this because when Python fails to get the OS-specific randomness source then by-default current system time is used as a seed value so perhaps it's relevant.

```
import random
import hashlib
import time

chrs = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
chrs = chrs.upper()

def nStr(n):
    ans = ""
    for k in range(0,n):
        ans+=chrs[int(random.random()*len(chrs))]
    return(ans)

def passes(h):
    tags = ["13370","00000000","11111111","22222222","33333333","44444444","55555555","66666666","77777777","88888888","99999999",
            "aaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbb","cccccccc","dddddddd","eeeeeeee","ffffffff"]
    match = False
    for k in tags:
        if h.startswith(k):
            match = True
            break
    return match

count = 0
s = nStr(64)
start = time.time()
t = 6
while time.time() - start < t:
    while time.time() - start < t:
        count+=1
        s = nStr(64)
        h = hashlib.sha256(s.encode()).hexdigest()
        if passes(h):
            break
    if passes(h):
        print(s)
        print(h)
        print()
print(f"hash rate: {count/t} hash/second")
```

[image: Output From running at Approximately 8:30 EST 3/10/2020]

And I know that pythons random module has a state property that looks like this:

```
>>> s = random.getstate
>>> dir(s)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__func__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
>>> def series(state,length):
...     random.setstate(state)
...     return [random.random() for k in range(length)]
...
>>> s = random.getstate()
>>> series(s,3)
[0.6578281745562433, 0.3851968268567585, 0.8303449881701223]
>>> series(s,3)
[0.6578281745562433, 0.3851968268567585, 0.8303449881701223]
>>> random.random()
0.5270977870567883
>>>
```

I'm wondering if there is **a way to retrieve the original state of random** when I ran this code and or the random state when the hashed sequence was generated... I didn't save it. Perhaps it's still on system memory although that feels like a separate question about pycharm specifically.
Any and all input is appreciated.

Edit: The terms seed and state seem to get a little confused here I think of the state as being the seed because seed is just state F(PRNG i=0) I use the 2 interchangeably and just ignoring the subtleties of i!=0.

Comment: So you have the state? What is it? From at what point? And out of curiosity: why are you interested in this?

Comment: If you know for sure that Python isn't using an OS randomness source, and you know that the system clock used by Python isn't too precise (say, only to the nearest millisecond), then it may be possible to do a brute force search over all possible seed times around the given time and date. Otherwise, without something like your system memory suggestion, this is as hard as predicting the next output of a pseudo-RNG given the previous outputs.

Comment: Btw after speeding it up I just had a run with seven passes, it's not that rare :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy I ran the program and the process exited I no longer have the state.

Comment: But your title says "from results and python random.getstate()".

Comment: @KellyBundy WelI I know that gestate gets me the random state I want to potentially change that to an old state that I no longer have.